# Need help counting characters in textfield using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Here is my problem:

I need to "enable" a button if the text is at least 5 characters long, and "disable" the button if it's less than 5 characters.

If the text is 5 characters long, I also add an $.click function to trigger a "whatever" function.
Now, I also need to "disable" this click function if it's less than 5 characters long.

But easier said than done. This is the code I have now, which is not working :)

```
<input id="userName" name="userName" class="textfield50pc" type="text" maxlength="50" value=""/>

jQuery('#userName').keydown(function()
{
    if((jQuery(this).val().length + 1) == 5)
    {
        jQuery("#guide_btnCreateGuide").css({'background-position':'top', 'cursor':'pointer'});
        jQuery("#guide_btnCreateGuide").click(function() { do something });
    }
    else if((jQuery(this).val().length - 2) < 5)
    {   
        jQuery("#guide_btnCreateGuide").css({'background-position':'bottom', 'cursor':'default'});
        // Here I really would like to disable whatever I added in the OnClick above. But how?
    }                          
});
```

I need some help getting this working.

**UPDATE**

Here is the solution based on help from this thread and [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031979/not-able-to-count-characters-using-jquery/2031993#2031993).

```
        jQuery('#input_guideName').keyup(function(e)
        {
            if(this.value.length == 5)
            {
                jQuery("#guide_btnCreateGuide").css({'background-position':'top', 'cursor':'pointer'});
                jQuery("#guide_btnCreateGuide").bind('click', function() { 
                    createNewGuide(); 
                });
            }
            else if(this.value.length < 5)
            {
                jQuery("#guide_btnCreateGuide").css({'background-position':'bottom', 'cursor':'default'});
                jQuery("#guide_btnCreateGuide").unbind('click');
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`bind`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/bind) the click event when it's 5 characters long and [`unbind`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/unbind) when it's less.

```
jQuery('#userName').keydown(function()
{
    jQuery("#guide_btnCreateGuide").unbind('click');
    if((jQuery(this).val().length + 1) == 5)
    {
        jQuery("#guide_btnCreateGuide").css({'background-position':'top', 'cursor':'pointer'});
        jQuery("#guide_btnCreateGuide").bind('click', function() { do something });
    }
    else if((jQuery(this).val().length - 2) < 5)
    {   
        jQuery("#guide_btnCreateGuide").css({'background-position':'bottom', 'cursor':'default'});
    }  
}
```

Comment: but then I will "unbind" it on each keudown less than 5? Maybe that doesn't matter? Another problem I have, is that I can't seem to change the button color if value is less than 5. The count goes all wrong :(

Comment: I changed the keydown function a bit. I think this way is better. Doesn't keep binding the event. I'm not sure I get what you mean by "the count goes all wrong". The button color and the count shouldn't be related. Can you describe in more detail?

Comment: The bind/unbind idea is spot on. But regarding the counting characters, your solution does not work. Se the above solution I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling the element instead of re-binding it?  I'm thinking this will allow you to bind the createguide button early, leave it bound, and simply toggle enable/disable per the username input.

```
$('#guide_btnCreateGuide').click(function() {
    // Do something  
});

$('#userName').keydown(function() {
    var username = $(this).val();
    if (username.length > 5) {
        $('guide_btnCreateGuide').attr('disabled', '')
    } else {
        $('guide_btnCreateGuide').attr('disabled', 'disabled')   
    }    
});
```

Comment: I think unbind will work(?). My problem now is counting characters. It's no problem counting up, it's counting down which is the problem.