# Not able to count characters using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I know I have a similar post, but it only answered part of my problem.

Her is my challenge to you: Can you make the alert display the correct number of characters?
Even when you press backspace?

Here is the code:

```
jQuery('#input_Name').keydown(function(e) {
  var count = $(this).val().length;
  alert(count+1);
});
```

Hint: The ascii key for backspace is 8 ( `if (e.keyCode != 8)` )

(I'm not able to get this right)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
jQuery('#input_Name').keyup(function(e) {
  var count = $(this).val().length;
  alert(count)
});
```

Comment: Extending "this" with jQuery on every keystroke will get pretty slow. Try this instead:
var count = this.value.length;

Comment: I really thought I tested that last night, when I got an infinite loop.... Thanks.